# Flexible results table, with columns based on the rows of another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I currently have the following table structure, Area, Cars, State, StateInfo, Repair. As a result, through an SQL query I get the table, OutComeTable.
So far, we have had a table of, State, defined for each repair shop since each one has different states, State1, State2 ...
since it depends on the repair positions that each workshop has.
What I want to achieve is, to be able to do the same, but that it works for all workshops regardless of the number of repair positions. That is, State1, State2, .... StateN. So the table, OutComeTable should be flexible adjusting to the amount of States, (rows) of the State table.
My current job structure:

Area

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | repair |
| 22 | paint |
| 23 | polish |

Cars

| id | car_code | brand | model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | zr12 | Subaru | Impreza |
| 2 | sd43 | Nissan | Qashqai |
| 3 | ra56 | Ford | Focus |

State

| id | name | level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | state1 | 1 |
| 2 | state2 | 2 |
| 3 | state3 | 3 |

StateInfo

| id | repaid_id | state_id | area_id | time_in | time_out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1290 | 2 | 1 |  |  |
| 2 | 1045 | 1 | 2 |  |  |
| 3 | 290 | 4 | 2 |  |  |

Repair

| id | repair_code | order_num | car_id | current_area_id | current_state_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DLM944 | 00123423 | 34 | 22 | 2 |
| 2 | LZM543 | 00123456 | 532 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | RFT411 | 00112235 | 234 | 23 | 3 |

OutComeTable

| repair_code | car_code | car_brand | car_model | state1_area | state2_area | state3_area | time_in | time_out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LZM543 | zr12 | Subaru | Impreza | repair | paint |  |  |  |
| DLM944 | sd43 | Nissan | Qashqai | repair |  |  |  |  |
| RFT411 | ra56 | Ford | Focus | repair | paint | polish |  |  |

And this is what I want to achieve, using the same tables except for State, the number of rows depends on the repair stations in each workshop.

Area

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | repair |
| 22 | paint |
| 23 | polish |

Cars

| id | car_code | brand | model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | zr12 | Subaru | Impreza |
| 2 | sd43 | Nissan | Qashqai |
| 3 | ra56 | Ford | Focus |

State

| id | name | level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | state1 | 1 |
| 2 | state2 | 2 |
| 3 | state3 | 3 |
|  |  |  |
| n | state_n | n |

StateInfo

| id | repaid_id | state_id | area_id | time_in | time_out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1290 | 2 | 1 |  |  |
| 2 | 1045 | 1 | 2 |  |  |
| 3 | 290 | 4 | 2 |  |  |

Repair

| id | repair_code | order_num | car_id | current_area_id | current_state_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DLM944 | 00123423 | 34 | 22 | 2 |
| 2 | LZM543 | 00123456 | 532 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | RFT411 | 00112235 | 234 | 23 | 3 |

OutComeTable

| repair_code | car_code | car_brand | car_model | state1_area | state2_area | state3_area | state_n_area | time_in | time_out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LZM543 | zr12 | Subaru | Impreza | repair | paint |  |  |  |  |
| DLM944 | sd43 | Nissan | Qashqai | repair |  |  |  |  |  |
| RFT411 | ra56 | Ford | Focus | repair | paint | polish |  |  |  |

Right now I handle the following SQL query, which represents the first form.

````
SELECT "Repair"."id", "Repair"."order_num", "Repair"."iqtime",

to_char((SELECT DATE_TRUNC('second', U0."timestamp" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Madrid') AS "trunc_ts" FROM "StateInfo" U0 WHERE (U0."repair_id" = "Repair"."id" AND U0."state_id" = 1) LIMIT 1), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS "tsadmin",
to_char((SELECT DATE_TRUNC('second', U0."timestamp" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Madrid') AS "trunc_ts" FROM "StateInfo" U0 WHERE (U0."repair_id" = "Repair"."id" AND U0."state_id" = 2) LIMIT 1), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS "tspre",
to_char((SELECT DATE_TRUNC('second', U0."timestamp" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Madrid') AS "trunc_ts" FROM "StateInfo" U0 WHERE (U0."repair_id" = "Repair"."id" AND U0."state_id" = 3) LIMIT 1), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS "tsquir",
to_char((SELECT DATE_TRUNC('second', U0."timestamp" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Madrid') AS "trunc_ts" FROM "StateInfo" U0 WHERE (U0."repair_id" = "Repair"."id" AND U0."state_id" = 4) LIMIT 1), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS "tsrecu",
to_char((SELECT DATE_TRUNC('second', U0."timestamp" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Madrid') AS "trunc_ts" FROM "StateInfo" U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "Area" U3 ON (U0."area_id" = U3."id") WHERE (U0."repair_id" = "Repair"."id" AND U0."state_id" = 5) LIMIT 1), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS "tsfin",
(SELECT U3."name" FROM "StateInfo" U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "Area" U3 ON (U0."area_id" = U3."id") WHERE (U0."repair_id" = "Repair"."id" AND U0."state_id" = 1) LIMIT 1) AS "aadmin",
(SELECT U3."name" FROM "StateInfo" U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "Area" U3 ON (U0."area_id" = U3."id") WHERE (U0."repair_id" = "Repair"."id" AND U0."state_id" = 2) LIMIT 1) AS "apre",
(SELECT U3."name" FROM "StateInfo" U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "Area" U3 ON (U0."area_id" = U3."id") WHERE (U0."repair_id" = "Repair"."id" AND U0."state_id" = 3) LIMIT 1) AS "aquir",
(SELECT U3."name" FROM "StateInfo" U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "Area" U3 ON (U0."area_id" = U3."id") WHERE (U0."repair_id" = "Repair"."id" AND U0."state_id" = 4) LIMIT 1) AS "arecu",
(SELECT CASE WHEN (U0."area_id" IS NULL AND U0."state_id" = 5) THEN 'MailBox' ELSE U3."name" END AS "alta_parsed_name" FROM "StateInfo" U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "Area" U3 ON (U0."area_id" = U3."id") WHERE (U0."repair_id" = "Repair"."id" AND U0."state_id" = 5) LIMIT 1) AS "afin",

"Cars"."wrist_band" AS "user", "airgoLocator_beacon"."name" AS "tag",
to_char((SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', U0."timestamp") AS "trunc_date" FROM "StateInfo" U0 WHERE (U0."repair_id" = "Repair"."id" AND U0."state_id" = 1) LIMIT 1), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "data_trunc" 

FROM "Repair" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Cars" ON ("Repair"."patient_id" = "Cars"."id") 

WHERE "Repair"."active" = False 

ORDER BY "tsadmin" ASC ```

How do I get a SQL code that allows me to do,that the, OutComeTable should be flexible adjusting to the amount of States, (rows) of the State table?
````

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should create a minimal reproducible example and share what you've tried so far, so that we can see exactly what you're struggling with. Cheers

Comment: I add my current SQL code, thanks